# Controlling the spacing between theorem environment and standard text

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, thmtools

I am using `thmtools` to typeset theorems.

The output I want is the following:

[image]

My question is about controlling the spacing between the `\hrule`s above and below the theorem environment.

I want the separation between the `hrule`s and the paragraphs above and below the theorem to be the same as the spacing between two adjacent paragraphs.

My current code for thmtools is:

```latex
\declaretheoremstyle[
...definitions about fonts..
    preheadhook=\vskip\parskip\hrule\relax,
    postfoothook=\hrule\relax,
    spaceabove=10pt,
    spacebelow=10pt
]{definition}
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter,style=definition]{theorem}
```

I am not sure if the latex code for `postfoothook` and `preheadhook` is correct. On the one side, if I don't change `\parskip` (that is, use the default of 0pt), the hrules are printed adjacent to the text above and below, as expected.

But if I pass a value, as in `\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}`, I don't think that the separation between the hrules and the paragraphs above and below is indeed 12 pts (after measuring distances with my pdf reader).

Am I wrong? How can I check it more systematically? What is the latex commands to pass to the two hooks so I get it right?

My code:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,kantlipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{12pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

    \declaretheoremstyle[
        headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, 
        notefont=\normalfont\bfseries,
        headpunct={},
        postheadspace=\newline,
        bodyfont = \normalfont,
        postfoothook=\hrule\relax,
        preheadhook=\vskip\parskip\hrule\relax,
        spaceabove=10pt,
        spacebelow=10pt
    ]{definition}
    \declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter,style=definition]{theorem}
\begin{document}
    
%\chapter{Introduction}
\kant[1-2]
\begin{theorem}
Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis nisl rhoncus.
\end{theorem}

\kant[3][1-3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To measure the vertical gaps, a few `\tikzmark` were added at selected places and then thin vertical lines were drawn with manually adjusted height using a `tikzpicture`.

See [using the tikzmark library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Griy.jpg). *But for this example, you don't need to understand tikz code*.

As seen in the figure, the space above and below the `\hrule` is 10pt as expected (green lines)

The `baselineskip` inside the theorem is 12pt --the default value for the book class with an 10pt font size-- and in the document the baselineskip + parskip is 24pt because of the 12pt added by `parskip` . (orange lines)

There is a discrepancy with the distance between the baseline of the upper and lower text lines and the `hrule` (red lines, 14pt and 12pt respectively. Wanted >> both 17pt).

[image: ori]

To obtain the desired spacing

(1) Used `\usepackage[skip=12pt]{parskip}` It will set the paragraphs to have no indentation and the parskip=12pt.

(2) Add vertical spaces before and after the rules to match the desired 17pt white space between paragraphs.

The result is now

[image: zz]

This is the code used for adjusting and measuring. It will auto adjust if the `skip` or the `\abovebelow` length are changed.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,kantlipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}% needed <<<<<<<<<<
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark} % needed <<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}% needed <<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[skip=12pt]{parskip} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<    

\newlength{\abovebelow} \setlength{\abovebelow}{10pt} % set spaces above & below <<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\htX}    \settoheight{\htX}{X} % adjust to font size
\newlength{\dtp}    \settodepth{\dtp}{p}    
    
\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\tikzmark{b}, % added a mark <<<<<<
notefont=\normalfont\bfseries,
headpunct={\tikzmark{c}}, % added a mark <<<<<<
postheadspace=\newline,
bodyfont = \normalfont,
postfoothook= \hrule height 0.1pt \vspace*{\dimexpr \baselineskip -\htX},%  changed <<<<<<
preheadhook=\vspace*{\dimexpr \baselineskip + \parskip- \htX- \dtp}\hrule height 0.1pt\vspace*{-\parskip}, %  changed <<<<<<
spaceabove=\abovebelow,%  changed <<<<<<
spacebelow=\abovebelow,%  changed <<<<<<
]{definition}

\declaretheorem[name=Xheorem,numberwithin=chapter,style=definition]{theorem}
\begin{document}
        
X Some  text
    
\tikzmark{g}Upper text.\tikzmark{a} % added a mark <<<<<<

\begin{theorem}
    Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis nisl rhoncus.\tikzmark{d} % added a mark <<<<<<
\end{theorem}

\tikzmark{f}Lower text.\tikzmark{e} % added a mark <<<<<<   

    % measure/check  vertical spaces <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \nprounddigits{1}
    \newlength{\bs}\setlength{\bs}{\baselineskip}%  
    \newlength{\pp} \setlength{\pp}{\dimexpr \baselineskip + \parskip}%  
    \newlength{\ub} \setlength{\ub}{\dimexpr \baselineskip + \parskip- \htX}%  
    \newlength{\br} \setlength{\br}{\dimexpr 2\baselineskip -\htX}%         
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture, every node/.style={right,midway,font=\tiny}]
        \draw [color=red]($ (pic cs:a) +(-1pt,0pt) $ ) -- ($ (pic cs:a) +(-1pt,-\ub) $)                 node[fill=gray!10]{$\lenprint{\ub}$}; % upper blank
        \draw [color=green]($ (pic cs:b) +(2pt,\htX) $ ) -- ($ (pic cs:b) +(2pt,\abovebelow+\htX) $)    node{\the\abovebelow}; %upper
        \draw [color=green]($ (pic cs:d) +(-1pt,0pt) $ ) -- ($ (pic cs:d) +(-1pt,-\abovebelow) $)       node{\the\abovebelow};  %lower
        \draw [color=red]($ (pic cs:f) +(2pt,\htX) $ ) -- ($ (pic cs:f) +(2pt,\ub+\htX) $)              node[fill=gray!10]{$\lenprint{\ub}$}; %blank to rule 
        \draw [color=orange]($ (pic cs:d) +(-1pt,0pt) $ ) -- ($ (pic cs:d) +(-1pt,\baselineskip) $)     node{\the\bs}; % baselineskip
        \draw [color=orange]($ (pic cs:a) +(-1pt,0pt) $ ) -- ($ (pic cs:a) +(-1pt,\pp) $)               node{\the\pp}; % baselineskip+parskip
        \draw [color=red]($ (pic cs:g) +(2pt,\htX) $ ) -- ($ (pic cs:g) +(2pt,\ub +\htX) $)             node[fill=gray!10]{$\lenprint{\ub}$}; %blamk to rule
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the final working code using above results.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools,kantlipsum} 

\usepackage[skip=12pt]{parskip} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\newlength{\abovebelow} \setlength{\abovebelow}{10pt} % set spaces above & below <<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\htX}    \settoheight{\htX}{X} % adjust to font size
\newlength{\dtp}    \settodepth{\dtp}{p}    

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries, %
notefont=\normalfont\bfseries,
headpunct={}, % 
postheadspace=\newline,
bodyfont = \normalfont,
postfoothook= \hrule \vspace*{\dimexpr \baselineskip -\htX},%  changed <<<<<<
preheadhook=\vspace*{\dimexpr \baselineskip + \parskip- \htX- \dtp}\hrule \vspace*{-\parskip}, %  changed <<<<<<
spaceabove=\abovebelow,%  changed <<<<<<
spacebelow=\abovebelow,%  changed <<<<<<
]{definition}
    
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter,style=definition]{theorem}
\begin{document}
    
\kant[1-2]
\begin{theorem}
    Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Sagittis nisl rhoncus.
\end{theorem}

\kant[3][1-3]
    
\end{document}
```

[image: yy]

Comment: Thanks very much for a much detailed answer. However (1) I don't understand why you used `\vspace*` and not the one without the asterisk (2) It's the first time that I see someone paying attention to the height and depth of the letters when they need to take control of parskip and baselineskip. Is this case I present here in this question so complicated that it requires that small resolutions of the depth of p and the height of x?

Comment: @tush Thank you for your comments! (1) with the * the space will be respected regardless of other spaces before or after, useful for this example. In real life, it will  add the space if the theorem starts a new page, so you might want to remove the * from the prehook if you don't like this behavior.

Comment: @tush 
(2) As for the ascenders and descenders, I did this because since your question didn't specify exactly where to measure the white space in each of the three cases, I took the liberty of interpreting it as optical white space, i.e. impact  in the eye of the reader. Removing that correction (for example, `\settoheight{\htX}{}` ), the spaces look uneven to my eyes. Also the three spaces will stay the same if you choose  `\documentclass[12pt]{book}`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand why there should be a mix of `\baselineskip` and `\parskip`. In particular, your suggested `postfoothook` is an `hrule` followed by `\vspace*{\dimexpr \baselineskip}`. Shouldn't it be `\vspace*{\dimexpr \parskip}` (give or take the depth/height of letters)?

Comment: @tush In your example both `parskip` and `baselineskip` have the same 12 pt. Try you suggestion using `skip=16pt`.

Comment: `skip=XX pt`? What is this length?

Comment: @tush  In `\usepackage[skip=16pt]{parskip}`  is the `parskip`

Comment: I never mentioned it in the original question, but my intention is to implement your solution to a Hebrew document. I just tried it and for some reason not all the distances are the same in my minimal Hebrew document. Can we talk about it in the chat or email?

Comment: @tush Try sidispa@gmail.com  I may not respond right away :)