# Get the height and depth of Hebrew letters

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, lengths, hebrew, height

I have seen [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661612/) the use of adding and subtracting the height and depth of the letter `X` and the letter `p` when defining vertical distances between objects on the document.

My document is in Hebrew and I want to calculate those lengths for some Hebrew letters. I tried to do

```
\newlength{\htX}    \settoheight{\htX}{ל}
```

and then in document to print the length with

```
\the\htX
```

but I get 0.0pt. Do you have any idea why?

MWE

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}

\newlength{\htX}    \settoheight{\htX}{ל}
\newlength{\dtp}    \settodepth{\dtp}{ן}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\the\htX~\the\dtp
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, at this point, the correct font has not been loaded yet. Try placing `\settoheight` and `\settodepth` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: That's right. They have to be inserted after begin document. Why is that? Can I make calculations with those lengths altought I get 0.0 pt?

Comment: You can also do `\settoheight{\htX}{\hebrewfont ל}` and `\settodepth{\dtp}{\hebrewfont ן}` but it might be safer to delay it until after the document has started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jasper Habicht and Qrrbrbirlbel for the comments. One can use `AtBeginDocument`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newlength{\htX}   \settoheight{\htX}{\hebrewfont ל}%
  \newlength{\dtp}   \settodepth{\dtp}{\hebrewfont ן}%
}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\setmathrm{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\the\htX~\the\dtp

\framebox[\dimexpr 0.25in+2\htX+6\dtp]{\strut}
\end{document}
```