# Spacing after \declaretheoremstyle

Tags: mdframed

I'm trying to implement a theoremstyle which is shaded and found a way by using `mdframed` in `\declaretheoremstyle` and it looks pretty good, but I want to increase the spacing after the text. Above the text I can control the spacing without any problems using `spaceabove`and `skipabove`, but the corresponding commands `spacebelow` and `skipbelow` don't work. Does anybody know why?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{amsproc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{xcolor, color}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\newcounter{counter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=0.5em,
spaceabove=10pt,
spacebelow=20pt,
mdframed={
    skipabove=10pt,
    skipbelow=0pt,
    hidealllines=true,
    backgroundcolor={gray!50!white},
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    innerrightmargin=10pt}
]{shaded}
\declaretheorem[style=shaded,sibling=counter]{aufgabe}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{aufgabe}
        \lipsum[1][4-7]
    \end{aufgabe}
    \lipsum[1][7-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `innerbottommargin=15pt`

Comment: Thank you, that is helpfull. But this does not increse the spacing after the shaded area. Above the theorem you could do it with `skipabove`, but `skipbelow` is not working.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661612/120578 Seems there ar some options but I didn't find them really good